Monitor HTTP request data for kubernetes microservice application
I have deployed a Java application in a Kubernetes cluster and am trying to figure out how to monitor it. So far I've managed to export logs, JVM metrics and traces through the Java open-telemetry agent. Through the open-telemetry collector this data ends up in Loki, Prometheus and Grafana Tempo respectively.
However when querying it from the Grafana UI this setup becomes very clumsy. The information I need seems difficult to query, or absent. Specifically I need to:

Get the throughput (requests per minute) to each microservice. TraceQL does not seem to have a rate function like PromQL.
Sort HTTP requests by handling time (how long they took). Maybe make some aggregations like "which paths are on average the slowest?". Tempo seems unsuitable to sort traces, and the Java agent does not export data about single HTTP calls obviously.

I looked at traces to perform this analysis because it seemed the most obvious place to look. Maybe it's just that Tempo is not the right backend? Should I store data somewhere else?

@ barmanthewise Did you have time to check my answer? It helped you to solve your problem? If the answer was useful, please mark the answer as accepted for greater visibility for the community or upvote if the answer has some useful information.

Thank you, I'm tryung out all the suggestions I received here. Once done I'll update this thread.

@  barmanthewise  I have provided an answer. If my answer solved your issue, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer. Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well.

However, while traces provide valuable information about request flow, they may not be the most efficient supply for particular metrics like request throughput and handling time. Here are some approaches to achieve your monitoring goals:
Monitoring throughput requests per minute: Use Prometheus as your primary data store for request throughput. The Java OpenTelemetry exporter is configurable to export http_requests_total HTTP request metrics with appropriate labels such as EX- direction, method, status code.
In Grafana, user promoQL to calculate the rate of these metrics over time functions like rate(http_requersts_totsl {path=” /users}” [5m] ) will calculate the request rate for the “/users” path over the last 5 minutes.
Monitoring Handling Time: The open Telemetry exporter can also expert histograms for request managing time (EX: http_server_duration_seconds)
In Grafana, visualize the distribution of request durations using histograms or percentiles. You can discover the sluggish paths with the aid of analyzing the percentiles.
NOTE: If you are comfortable with seller-specific solutions, recollect application Insights depending upon your cloud provider. It can collect request telemetry facts and offer dashboards for visualizing request throughput and dealing with times.
While Tempo is a great preference for traces Jaeger is another popular option. Both provide comparable querying functionalities. Consider exploring integrations with Zipkin or Jaeger in case your visualization tools are specially designed for those backends.
Refer to this Signoz blog1 and blog2 by Ankit Anand.

This is interesting. However I cannot find the http_request_total setting in the java agent docs here https://opentelemetry.io/docs/zero-code/java/agent/configuration/

you are correct, the http_request_total configuration is not explicitly mentioned in the Open Telemetry Java agent documentation. However, that functionality you want is done by automatic instrumentation provided by the agent.

OpenTelemetry agent automatically prepares such common libraries as Spring MVCservlet etc. for HTTP requests.This implies it collects metrics and spans automatically for HTTP requests without needing to manually set particular metric names like http_request_total.

Check this document out to get more details. It will help you solve your problem.

@ barmanthewise  It helped you to solve your problem? If the answer was useful, please mark the answer as accepted for greater visibility for the community or upvote if the answer has some useful information.

Sorry I still don't see how to enable this metric from the docs you provided.

The http_server_requests_total metric is typically enabled by default in the Open Telemetry Java agent when it automatically instruments supported web frameworks

see this GITHUB link  for more information.
